# Java : Wild card File search in Folder

Tags: java, wildcard

I have one folder which contain list of File. I want to search Files.

eg. 1. TBC_DICV_11943_IGAXMLService__V1.0

Search keywords are TBC*IGAXML*1* , *1.0, *IGAXMLService* etc

EXEC_DICV_SERVICE_TEST

Search keywords are   *DICV*,  *Test
Please can you help to search ?

Comment: That's nice. did you have a question?

Comment: Why don't you try something on your own?

Comment: Why cannot you try `String.contains()` ??

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Glad to meet you in here ☺️ Am I correct that `String.contains()` help in this case??

Comment: @Sibidharan: Same here... hope that you are doing good. Let's ping in FB :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String serachkeyword;
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(serachkeyword);
File[] files = new File(path).listFiles(fileFilter);
List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(files));
```

serachkeyword are TBC*IGAXML*1* , *1.0, IGAXMLService etc

Its working fine.

Thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this `

```
List<String>arrlist=new ArrayList<String>();
   arrlist.add("what ever u wants");// add more
        for(int i=0;i<arrlist.size();i++)
  {
  if(arrlist.get(i).equals(" TBC_DICV_11943_IGAXMLService__V1.0"));
   {
    System.out.println("match found do your stuff here");
    }
   }
```

Comment: If you are able to do it with `equals`, there is no point in doing it like this - it is more efficient simply to use `ArrayList.contains`. I think the point of the question is that OP wants to do a wildcard search. (Also, use an iterator or an enhanced for loop).

Comment: Please delete this answer, This answer is not related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with a Stream and a Pattern:

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("foo");
        list.add("TBC_DICV_11943_IGAXMLService__V1.0");
        list.add("bar");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("TBC.*IGAXML.*1.*");
        list.stream().filter(value -> pattern.matcher(value).find()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: There may be or may not be n number of *

Comment: This approach is flexible enough to be able to use any regexp you want simply modify Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(<my-regexp-here>);